Is it possibile to apply mesh material to Geometry nodes scatter without UVs?
I have a mesh witha a painterly brick-like texture that I have applied a geometry nodes setup to in order to dissolve/explode the bricks via instances populated in a point volume.
I want to have the painted texture be applied to the geometry nodes, but I seem to just get a flat color when i use a "set material" node.   I assume it's because I have the material mapped to "generated" rather than "uv".
Is there a way to apply the generated texture across the instances of the geonodes the way it is applied to the base mesh? This is just a concept piece so I want to avoid dealing with UVs.
Thanks!
